# A question about moment generating function

Tags: probability, reference-request, moment-generating-functions

I am reading the [lecture notes](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/mgf_color.pdf) where proposition 6.3.1. says:

> Suppose that the moment-generating function $m_Y(t)$ of a random variable $Y$ admits an expansion into a power series. Then the coefficients are related to the moments of $Y$ in the following way:
> $$ m_Y(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\mu_k}{k!}t^k, $$ where $\mu_k=\mathbb E[Y^k]$ is the $k$-th moment of $Y$.

And it is said: "A fully rigorous argument of this proposition is beyond the scope of these
notes".

But it is followed by the following line:

$$ m_Y(t)=\mathbb E[e^{tY}]=\mathbb E[\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(tY)^k}{k!}]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty t^k\frac 1{k!}\mathbb E[Y^k]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {\mu_k}{k!}t^k. $$

I think this is already rigorous if say $Y$ is positive by the [Fubini-Tonelli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Fubini%E2%80%93Tonelli_theorem). But why does this also hold even when $Y$ is an arbitrary random variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about the positive case. In general $Y$ need not have finite moments and even when the moments exits you need conditions on the moments for this to hold.

Suppose $Ee^{c|Y|} <\infty$ for some $c >0$ (equivalently, $\sum \frac {|\nu_k|} {k!} c^{k} <\infty$ where $\nu_k$ is the $k-$th absolute moment of $Y$). Then DCT can be used to justify the equation $m_Y(t)=\sum \frac {\mu_k t^{k}} {k!}$ for $|t| <c$.

Comment: Any counterexample for why this is necessary?

Comment: If $Y$ takes the value $n$ with probability $ae^{-\sqrt n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z$  (where $a$ is such that $a \sum e^{-\sqrt n}=1$) then $Y$ has moments of all orders but $m_Y(t)=\infty$ for all $t \neq 0$. @b

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be any random variable with $\mathbb E\left[e^{tX}\right]<\infty$ for all $|t|<a$, for some $a>0$.

Therefore,

$$\mathbb E\left[e^{|tX|}\right]\le\mathbb E\left[e^{tX}\right]+\mathbb E\left[e^{-tX}\right]<\infty \quad,\,\forall \,|t|<a \tag{1}$$

Now $e^{|tX|}\ge \frac{|tX|^k}{k!}$ for every $k\in \mathbb N$. So by choosing a $t$ in $(0,a)$, we have $$\mathbb E|X|^k <\infty \quad,\forall \,k\ge 1$$

Also for every $n\in\mathbb N$, $$\left|\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(tX)^k}{k!}\right|\le \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{|tX|^k}{k!}\le e^{|tX|} \tag{2}$$

$(1)$ and $(2)$ ensure that we can write the 2nd equality here by applying DCT:

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[e^{tX}\right]&=\mathbb E\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(tX)^k}{k!}\right]
\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb E\left[\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(tX)^k}{k!}\right]
\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{t^k}{k!} \mathbb E\left[X^k\right]
\\&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^k}{k!}\mathbb E\left[X^k\right]
\end{align}